# Azure Ad access token clarifications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need clarification with sample or reference link for below items:

1. How to enable automatic renewal of access token?
2. How to get active access token and expiry time ?
3. Is there any possible ways to get Ad username, password and client id again from access token?
4. How to validate access token ?

It all needs to be implement in c# not in powershell.

Comment: try it your self with follow tutorials and ask conflict or errors you had. follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios

Answer (score 0):

> > How to enable automatic renewal of access token?

Upon successful authentication , Azure AD returns two tokens: a JWT access token and a JWT refresh token .When the access token expires, the client application will receive an error that indicates the user needs to authenticate again. If the application has a valid refresh token, it can be used to acquire a new access token without prompting the user to sign in again. If the refresh token expires, the application will need to interactively authenticate the user once again.

> > How to get active access token and expiry time ?

For how to authenticate users and get an Azure AD access token for your azure ad  app , you could refer to [Authentication Scenarios for Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#claims-in-azure-ad-security-tokens) .The Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) enables client application developers to easily authenticate users to cloud or on-premises Active Directory (AD), and obtain access tokens for securing API calls.  ADAL is available on a variety of platforms. You could find code samples and common scenario in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) .

> > Is there any possible ways to get Ad username, password and client id again from access token?

You could get decode the access token , find the `upn` claim which Stores the user name of the user principal ; `appid` claim identifies the application that is using the token to access a resource. Please refer to document :[Azure AD token reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims) .And of course ,you can't get password information .

> > How to validate access token ?

JWT tokens are signed, but not encrypted when received. It must [validate the signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims#validating-tokens) to prove the token's authenticity and validate a few claims in the token to prove its validity. The claims validated by an app vary depending on scenario requirements, but there are some common claim validations that your app must perform in every scenario.For example, we need to verify the `iss` and `aud` claim if you were developing a single tenant app. And you also need to verify the `nbf` to ensure the token is not expired. For more details , please refer to [Validating tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims#validating-tokens) .

[Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/) is a code sample for how to manually validating a JWT access token in a web API .  And if you were using the OWIN components in your project, it is more easy to verify the token by using `UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication` extension , code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect) is for your reference .

Comment: Note that, the access token should be considered as opaque (and could be crypted in the future). We don't recommend that you extract claims from the access token. It's only supposed to be consumed by the resource (not the client)

Comment: Also the renewal of the tokens is done on the client libraries (for C# you can use ADAL.Net if you want to target Azure AD V1 (that is for Work/School accounts and ADFS on premise accounts), and you can use MSAL.Net if you want to target Azure AD V2, which is for Work/School accounts and MSA (Microsoft personal accounts)

Comment: For C# client libraries, see [Azure Active Directory Authentication Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries)